# Adding row to dataframe without reset index

Tags: python, pandas

I built a dataframe, but came across an error where when I tried to append in place, it would only add one row. I found the solution for this was for me to reset the index. I am wondering if someone has insight as to why this was happening.

The code follows the logic of, drop duplicates, generate new data and add to the end. After dropping the index is off which is why I assume it isn't working but not sure the exact detials

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset=['statement'], inplace=True)
data = data[(data.statement.str.len() <= 130) & (data.statement.str.len() >= 5)]

# There is lots of logic but this is the append statement
data.loc[len(data)] = [statement, row.topic_direction, row.topic, row.direction]

# In this loop if I print len(data) 
# it increases once for the first add and then never again
```

Note: if someone comes across this it can be solved with resetting your index:

```
data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: would you like show us some sample data ?

Comment: drop duplicates messes all the indexes, so a reset index needs to done after you do drop duplicates...

Comment: @Wen I am not allowed to show the data as part of company policy sorry.